# Find if point inside polygon on google maps using python

Tags: python, google-maps, maps

I would like to know if I can use google maps api to check if a point (lat, long) is within a given polygon (list of vertices) via the back-end using python or i will have to compulsory write a python algo for that.

Comment: You might be able to to use containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon) in the geometry library https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry?hl=en#containsLocation

Comment: @Verma Thats for javascript. I said back-end (python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a straightforward way of doing this using Google Map API and Python.

If you have the point and polygon coordinates available, it will certainly be easier doing this using the Python library [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely). Here is an example code using Shapely:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
pt = Point(0.75, 0.25)
poly = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
poly.contains(pt)
```